# Passing tensorflow records one by one

Tags: python, tensorflow, record

The tensorflow record size is very huge 100 GB storing 1000 mini-batches.
But I will need 10000 mini-batches.
If a tensorflow record is created while the program is running replacing the old tensorflow record, how can I place the newly created record in the queue?

Do I need to have all the tensorflow records before running the tensorflow code or can I pass one by one, creating each when the last one is over.

```
# Writing to a tf.record.
result_tf_file = file_path_prefix + '.tfrecords'
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(result_tf_file)
# Create feature
features = tf.train.Features(feature=d_feature)
example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
serialized = example.SerializeToString()
writer.write(serialized)


# For Initializing the tf.record.
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([file_name_tf])
dataset = dataset.map(m)
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=50)
dataset = dataset.repeat(1)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

# Initializing iterator
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={file_name_tf: result_tf_file})
```

Can I initialize like
sess.run(iterator.initializer, serialized)?

Comment: You could have an initializable iterator and use a placeholder as records file name. Then you can generate one file, initialize iterator, train with that, generate second file, initialize, train, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @jdehesa. It is very helpful.

Comment: @jdehesa If I create one tensorflow record at a time and initialize each time with an initializable iterator, is it possible not to create the tensorflow record but return the serialized example. And initialize the serialized example with an initializable iterator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the serialized example", and by "initialize the serialized example with an initializable iterator". Maybe you can edit the question to give some more details.

Comment: I was writing to tf.record and reading from it. Wondering if I can return serialized and initialize it using iterator.

Comment: Yes, you can have tensors of `tf.string` dtype containing serialized [`tf.train.Example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example) objects, then either use [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_example) or, if within a dataset (using `map` method), [`tf.parse_single_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example). It's the same as with [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset) really, but from bytes data instead of TFRecord files.

Comment: Thank you :). I will try with this.